# Insert into with interval date from lastest date other table to current date SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008

I want to get the data from date parameter on other table, and use it on the table.

For example, I have a Table_A that looks like this:

[image]

And Table_B like this:

[image]

From Table A and B, I want insert with the parameter between last date from `Table_A.last_job_update` and `GETDATE()` with data from Table_B, and insert it into `Table_C`.

Here are my SQL statement for this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.Table_A ON

INSERT INTO test.table_A (product_id, product_name, status, last_update)
    SELECT product_id, product_name, status, last_update 
    FROM test.Table_B
    WHERE last_update = (SELECT MAX(last_update) 
                         FROM test.PF_HKMN_TEST_TABLE 
                         WHERE Table_B.product_name = Table_B.product_name)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.table_A OFF;
```

From my SQL statement above only can get the specific date, not range date to currentdate.

**SOLUTION**

table_A : Source

table_B : Date Parameter

table_C : Destination

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = GETDATE()

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.table_C ON;

INSERT INTO test.table_C (product_id, product_name, status, last_update)
SELECT product_id, product_name, status, last_update
FROM test.table_A
WHERE last_update BETWEEN (select max(last_job_update) FROM test.table_B) and Date;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.table_C OFF;
```

Comment: What is your expected output? I don't understand what `only can get the specific date, not range date to currentdate` means. And I don't see a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. I am not really understand what you want. What is the table PF_HKMN_TEST_TABLE?
I try to guess what you want.

```
WITH cteTestA
     AS (SELECT product_id, 
                last_job_update, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id
                ORDER BY last_job_update DESC) AS rn
         FROM Table_A)
     INSERT INTO table_C
            (product_id, 
             product_name, 
             STATUS, 
             last_update
            )
     SELECT b.roduct_id, 
            b.product_name, 
            b.STATUS, 
            b.last_update
     FROM Table_B AS b
          INNER JOIN cteTestB AS ctea
          ON ctea.product_id = b.product_id
             AND b.rn = 1
     WHERE b.last_update BETWEEN ctea.last_job_update AND GETDATE();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have found the solution, I have add my solution on my question. thank you before

Comment: @RudyTriSaputra rather than adding your solution to your question, please instead add it as an additional answer.